# Macbook retina display breaks website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, retina-display

I'm currently developing a website locally (otherwise, I would link directly to it), and I'm doing some final debugging on a few devices.  The problem I've encountered is that on a Macbook Pro with Retina display it forces the website overall to a smaller resolution width.

Here's what it looks like on a windows desktop:
[image: Standard Desktop]

And here's what it's doing on the Macbook Pro:
[image]

I haven't encountered this before.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  Let me know if there's anything else I need to provide.

Not sure if it's worth mentioning, but this is the only device it's giving me a problem on.  It responds correctly to android and ios tablets and phones.

Other things possibly worth noting;
My breakpoints are as follows:

```
$S:     320px;   
$M:     768px;     
$L:     1170px;
```

and my meta viewport is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided,
Bc.

Comment: You should provide the html and css for that row of icons and the container it's in.

Comment: Check your browser zoom is at 100%

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I only posted an image to that section, because that's the most obvious place the problem appears, however, it's the entire site that's being "zoomed in" on the Macbook Pro.  Here's a link to a fiddle I set up with that container and icons.  It's a little messy at the moment as I've been trying to figure out what's happening.  I'm currently trying it with a max-width: 978px query to simplify it a little bit more.

Comment: That was our first thing to check.  We had to zoom out to 67% to get it to display everything appropriately on the Macbook.

@FakeRainBrigand Thank you guys for such a quick response.  Appreciate the fast efforts to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion to anyone trying to help.  Something that would have been worth mentioning is that the Macbook Pro is a 13" laptop, which I've come to realize the retina scales down to 1280px width.  I was under the impression it was larger and we're still developing the tablet version.

I apologize if I've wasted anyone's time.

Thank you to the ones that tried to help,
Bc.